# MVC - Sending List of Values to AJAX call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

I have a Modal that opens & gives User options to check some checkboxes. When the User checks checkboxes of his choice. I want to send all the values of checkboxes & call AJAX method.

I want to send values of selected checkboxes to the Controller method.

Here is my Code :-

```
// These are dynamic checkboxes - This is just an e.g
<input type="checkbox" name="name" value="Code">
<input type="checkbox" name="name" value="Code1">
<input type="checkbox" name="name" value="Code2">
<input type="checkbox" name="name" value="Code3">

// onClick event of Button
 jq.get('/Controller/getData', function (data) {
      jq('#placeHolder').html(data);
 });

 // Controller
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult getData()
 {   
      return PartialView("_pagepartial");
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the values of the checked checked boxes and add to an array

```
var array = [];
$('input:checked').each(function() {
  array.push($(this).val());
}
```

And to pass to you controller

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: '@Url.Action("getData", "Controller")',
  dataType: "html",
  traditional: true,
  data: { values: array},
  success : function (data) {
    $('#placeHolder').html(data);
  }
});
```

assuming you controller method is

```
public ActionResult getData(string[] values)
{
  // return some partial view based on values
}
```

Comment: Just tested and it works fine - the key is to use `traditional: true` because its an array. Suggest you check the the value of `array` in the console.

Comment: You missed a closing bracket.

`var array = [];
$('input:checked').each(function() {
  array.push($(this).val());
})`